# R: How to get rid of rows depending on a calculation applied in a certain column, that refers to values of other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df with the columns subject(subj), condition, reaction time(rt_link). Each row is one trial. I calculated the means and SDs of RTs per subject and Condition:

```
RTs_overview <- links_RTs %>% 
  group_by(subj, condition) %>% 
  summarize(mean_rt = mean(rt_link),
            sd_rt = sd(rt_link))
```

and it gives out a nice df showing the subject, the condition and mean and SD of RTs each, so there are 4 rows per subject, one for each condition.
I would now like to get rid of all rows where the RT is > or < 3SDs of the mean of the corresponding subject and condition. Earlier, I got rid of rows with RTs > 10s, with this:

```
links_RTs <- links_cl[links_cl$rt_link < 10, ]
```

I tried to do the same now, but unsuccessfully

```
links_RTs[links_RTs$rt_link < (lapply(mean(links4_RTs$rt_link) + 3 * sd(links4_RTs$rt_link))), ]
```

I also tried it without lapply, but this too did not work.

How can I delete every row where rt_link is > or < than 3SDs from the corresponding rt-mean (depending on the subject and condition)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to retain decision-making criteria in the original dataset and then subset based on those criteria:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(99)

# Define raw data
dat <- data.frame(subj = rep(1:25, 8),
           condition = rep(c("A","B", "C", "D"), 200),
           rt_link = runif(200, 0, 1))

dat %>% 
  group_by(subj, condition) %>% 
  mutate(mean_rt = mean(rt_link)) %>%
  mutate(sd_rt = sd(rt_link)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(upr = mean_rt + (sd_rt*3)) %>%
  mutate(lwr = mean_rt - (sd_rt*3)) %>%
  mutate(remove = ifelse(rt_link > upr | rt_link < lwr, 1, 0))

    subj condition rt_link mean_rt   sd_rt   upr     lwr remove
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1 A           0.585   0.321 0.282   1.17  -0.524       0
 2     2 B           0.114   0.462 0.372   1.58  -0.654       0
 3     3 C           0.684   0.709 0.0264  0.788  0.630       0
 4     4 D           0.993   0.541 0.482   1.99  -0.905       0
 5     5 A           0.535   0.582 0.0505  0.734  0.431       0
 6     6 B           0.967   0.827 0.149   1.27   0.380       0
 7     7 C           0.671   0.508 0.174   1.03  -0.0147      0
 8     8 D           0.295   0.442 0.158   0.916 -0.0315      0
 9     9 A           0.358   0.249 0.117   0.600 -0.101       0
10    10 B           0.175   0.167 0.00939 0.195  0.138       0
# ... with 790 more rows
```

then filter:

```
mydat <- dat[dat$remove == 0,]
```